# How to send gatling request with AWS Signature Version 4?

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, rest, api, gatling

I am trying to automate a scenario where I need to generate load on Pods which are hosted on AWS. They require authentication with "AWS Signature Version 4".

I am not sure how to send a request with "AWS Signature Version 4" via Gatling. 
AWS Signature Version 4 takes these values.

1. AccessKey
2. SecretKey
3. AWS Region
4. Service Name

Returns

```
"X-Amz-Date":
"Authorization": "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=AccessKey/us-east-1/apigateway/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=content-length;content-type;host;x-amz-date, Signature="somevalue",
```

Does giving all the values like this will help?

```
.exec(http("RESTGetOAuthToken")
          .post("")
          .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
          .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
          .header("X-Amz-Date", "")
          .header("Authorization", "")
          .header("Cache-Control", "no-cache")
        .body(StringBody("""{
  "orders": [
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to generate X-Amz-Date and Authorization details and pass them along with the header. You can use the below class to extract this two information.

https://github.com/sandipperf/AWS_API_Request_Gatling/blob/master/RequestSigner.scala to extract AWS signature key by providing ASWAccessKey and AWSSecretKey.

**Here is how you can extract information from your scala test class after importing RequestSigner class **

```
val AwsAccessKey = "XXXXXXXXXXXX"
val AwsSecretKey = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
val signature = RequestSigner.sign(
        uriPath = "/Your/URL/HERE",

        method = "POST",
        //body = Some("""{ "hello": "foo" }"""),
        body = Some(requestBuildBody),
       //requestBuildBody = your actual request body you are going to pass along with post request 

        headers = Seq(("Host", List("XXXXXXXX.execute-api.us-XXXX-2.amazonaws.com"))),
        queryParameters = Seq.empty,
        credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(AwsAccessKey, AwsSecretKey),
        region = "us-XXXX-2",
        service = "execute-api")


      val amzStamp = (signature.toString).substring(18, 34)
      val sign = (signature.toString).substring(35, 223)
      AmazonTimeDetails.append(amzStamp).toString
      SignatureDetails.append(sign).toString
```

**From above code you will get X-Amz-Date and  signatureDetails , which you need to use in header**

```
    "Host" -> "XXXXXX.execute-api.us-XXXX-X.amazonaws.com",
    "Content-Type" -> "application/json",
    "X-Amz-Date" -> "${amazonTimeDetails}",
    "Authorization" -> "${signatureDetails}")
```